# Permission error when setting IAM policy on Artifact Registry in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm following [this](https://wlyn.ch/posts/gcp-tekton-workload-identity/) guide and getting stuck at step 3.  When I run

```
gcloud artifacts repositories add-iam-policy-binding [myrepo] \
--location us \
--member=serviceAccount:build-robot@[myproject].iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/artifactregistry.writer
```

I get `PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission`.

gcloud is running as roles/Owner (myself) so I definitely have permission to perform the action.

I can add a project binding for the service account with role `roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder`, and this works (I can push and pull images from the artifact registry using the build-robot service account), but is far too permissive for what I want the service account to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this error may happen due to the specified location in the `--location` tag not being the correct one.

Check that the artifact to which you're granting permissions is in US, as the tutorial you shared assumes you've created it in US, or otherwise change the location tag accordingly.

Comment: That did it!  needed to specify location="us-central1" rather than just "us"